# Where is the safest country in Africa?

Tags: safety, africa

As the title asks, which African country is safe for visiting with peace of mind?

Comment: @Simon lots of African countries are scene of military conflicts, so they are easily eliminated.

Comment: Asking such a question for countries as a whole does not make sense. In south Africa there are some pretty dangerous areas. But if you do not go there, there is no "safety issue". There are places in South Africa, which are much "safer" than many places in the US or Europe.

Comment: If I have to nominate one single and entire country here, it will be Cape Verde.

Comment: What type of safety matters most: health, traffic, petty crime, terrorism ... ?

Comment: @MarcelC. I wonder why you and others consider downvoting and closing this question, and the answer given clearly justify the question. `The Canada and UK Travel Advisory sites list only one African country where one should apply normal security precautions which is the same as most of Europe, Australia and the USA.` Then, it was answerable and constructive to know which African country is considered safest as suggested by travel advisories.

Comment: The downvotes are not mine. I have not voted at all

Comment: And as I have said above, you have to define what you mean by "safest". That's a vague concept

Comment: I guess island countries like Mauritius and Madagascar would be safe.

Comment: Safe for whom? For locals? tourists? expats? rich locals? poor locals? of different ethnicity to the locals? (and therefore easy to recognize, mug, kidnap etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Botswana is generally recommended as quite safe. The UK government's [travel advisory](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/botswana) seems to support this (if it sounds scary to you, just compare it with those of some countries you know - a "general threat of terrorism" seems to be listed for every single country in the world).

Comment: It is okay as long as you don't drive too much. Road safety is poor.

Comment: +1. The [Canada Travel Advisory site](http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/advisories) also lists it as the only African country where one should apply *normal security precautions* which is the same as most of Europe, Australia and the USA.

Comment: The same can be said about Cape Verde. I would even say that from the sanitary point of view it is safer!